# Proof if $A$ is normal then it is nondefective

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

What is the proof that if $A$ ($m\times m$ Matrix)  is normal i.e $(AA^{\ast} = A^{\ast}A)$ then $A$ is non defective i.e (for each eigenvalue of $A$, its algebraic multiplicity is equal to the geometric multiplicity).

Comment: The simplest way is probably through the [Schur form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition). Show that $A$ is normal iff its Schur (triangular) form is normal which turns out to lead to a diagonal matrix. See, e.g., [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039530/new-proof-about-normal-matrix-is-diagonalizable).

Answer (score 1):

It follows from:

- A normal matrix is diagonalizable.
- For a diagonalizable matrix algebraic and geometric multiplicity coincide.

Both are quite standard results.

Comment: Thanks .. I was able to find the proof for the first one and it clears the picture :)