# Show that $A^2=A$ suppose that A is normal and $A^5=A^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, diagonalization

In the beginning this seems easy to me - just multiply $A^{-3}$ on both sides, but I realized that $A$ and its associated diagonal matrix $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ are not nessarily invertible. So what else can I try? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show this if $A$ is diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$A$ is normal $\implies$ $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1039548/260674), i.e. $A=P^*\Lambda P$ for the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ of eigenvalues of $A$ and a unitary matrix $P$. This is actually an if and only if statement.

Comment: Oh this is really obvious now: we have $A^5 = P^*\mathbf{\Lambda}^{5}P = P^*\mathbf{\Lambda}^{4}P = A^4$, this must require that either $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is the null matrix or the identity matrix. So we conclude that $A^2 = P^*\mathbf{\Lambda}^{2}P = P^*\mathbf{\Lambda}P = A$. Is this correct? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LeoC, you can only conclude that the entries of $\Lambda$ are $0$ or $1$, but they need not be all equal

Comment: @lhf Yes you're right. I actually just realized that and seems the result still holds. Thanks!

Comment: @LeoC., I suggest you write your own answer combining the hint here and the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this question myself as @lhf suggested and see if I am correct...

---

Since $A$ is normal, by [Spectral Theorem for Normal Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices), there exists some diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=UDU^*$. So we have

$$ A^{5} = (UDU^*)^{5} = \underbrace{(UDU^*)\cdots(UDU^*)}_{5 \text{ times}} = UD\ (UU^*)\ D\ (U\cdots U^*)\ DU^*=UD^{5}U^*$$

and similarly for $A^{4}$. Then

$$UD^{5}U^* = UD^{4}U^*$$

this implies for $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n), \lambda_i=0\text{ or }1 \text{ for } i\in[n].$ Therefore
$$A^2=UD^{2}U^*=UDU^*=A.$$

---

Moreover, we can show that $A$ is actually Hermitian:

$$\begin{aligned}
A^*&=(UDU^*)^* \\
   &=(U^*)^*D^*U^*\\
   &=UDU^* \text{ as D is real from above}\\
   &= A
\end{aligned}$$